# How can I delete a rEFInd boot entry?

Tags: debian, refind

I'd like to remove the first entry to leave only the Debian entry, with GRUB I know how to do it but how can I with rEFInd?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it says "Boot EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi from 196 MiB FAT volume".

That most likely refers to your ESP partition, which is typically mounted as `/boot/efi` in Debian. So the full path as you would see it in Debian would be `/boot/efi/EFI/GRUB/grubx64.efi`.

Debian's UEFI GRUB would normally be in `/boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi`, so this looks like you may have tried building GRUB from sources and install it in a distribution-independent way. If this instance of GRUB was just an experiment you no longer need, you could simply delete the entire `/boot/efi/EFI/GRUB` directory. Once deleted, rEFInd will no longer have anything to auto-detect there, and will of course no longer show the extra entry.

But if you want to keep that instance of GRUB and just hide it from rEFInd, find rEFInd's configuration file (perhaps at `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf`?) and add a line like this to the end of the file:

```
dont_scan_dirs +,/EFI/GRUB
```

This should tell rEFInd that it should ignore the `/boot/efi/EFI/GRUB` directory (which it sees as `EFI\GRUB\`) and leave anything inside it alone.

The plus sign on the `dont_scan_dirs` line means "don't override any previous `dont_scan_dirs` lines if there is any; just add this directory to the list of directories to ignore."